# Update figure text in matplotlib figure in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

How to update figure text in matplotlib figure in python 2.7?

```py
t = figtext(.78,.92, "Combined- Sensors ", horizontalalignment = 'center',fontsize=15,color= 'm')
```

I have tried using `t.remove()` but I am getting an error:

```py
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\combined.py", line 245, in <module>
    t.remove()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 137, in remove
    raise NotImplementedError('cannot remove artist')
NotImplementedError: cannot remove artist
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove a the figtext using the code below, assuming your `figtext` object has been saved to a variable `t`.

```
plt.gcf().texts.remove(t)
plt.draw()
```

`plt.gcf()` will get the current figure object. If you already have the figure object, say for example you created it with `fig = plt.figure()` before doing your plotting, then you can just use `fig.texts.remove(t)`.

You need to call `plt.draw()` after you have removed the object to re-draw the plot and hence show the removal.